# WCF ServiceRoute POST 405 method not allowed

Tags: c#, wcf

I get an error on any `OperationContract` with `POST`: `405 method not allowed` 
`GET` work just fine. I've tried it on local and remote server with the webserver e.g. `localhost/myPostMethod/myParam`

I host the service like these :

```
   RouteTable.Routes.Add(
        new ServiceRoute(@"Default",
            new CustomWebServiceHostFactory(),
            typeof(DefaultService)));
```

(i use the webHttpBinding inside my CustomWebServiceHostFactory)
Can not change any settings inside IIS on my remote server. I think it's not necessary ether. Seems like the problem is somewhere inside my code.

Tried many thinks and i'm a little bit desperate right now. Would be very happy about any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added header... Solved.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```